# How to get an intersection of two linked lists?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Hi i am learning data structures and algorithms and practicing questions from leetcode
I came across a [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/), and I tried understanding it, but i am not able to understand it.
In example1 there are two linked list
where

```
listA = [4,1,8,4,5]
listB = [5,6,1,8,4,5]
```

then why the intersection point of these two linked lists is 8? and not 1?
because what i am assuming is the point from where both the lists become SAME, is the intersection point.

Because in example2 there are 2 lists

```
listA = [1,9,1,2,4]
listB = [3,2,4]
```

in this the intersection point is '2'. because the lists become same from '2'

Please explain me this concept of intersection.

Thank you

Comment: `listA = [4,1,8,4,5] listB = [5,6,1,8,4,5]` is **not** the input, the provided **picture** is the input. That the values are the same doesn't matter, you need to look at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

See the picture below:

[image]

The linked list `A` and `B` are having nodes with same value (e.g., nodes having value 1) but they are actually two different nodes. The intersection starts at `node` having value 8.

The intersection means linked list having same nodes. It doesn't mean they have different nodes with same value.

To check for intersection, you can't rely on nodes having same value. They should be same node (nodes having same address).

The algorithm is to first find the length of both linked list. Move the larger linked list head by difference of lengths of both linked-list. Then, check if nodes are actually equal by `address` (not just value).

See my [Solution](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/510765958/):

```
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def get_length(h):
        ln = 0
        while h:
            ln += 1
            h = h.next
        return ln

    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        l1 = Solution.get_length(headA)
        l2 = Solution.get_length(headB)

        print(l1, l2)
        lg = headA if l1 > l2 else headB
        sr = headA if l1 <= l2 else headB

        for _ in range(abs(l2 - l1)):
            lg = lg.next

        while lg and sr:
            if lg == sr:
                return lg
            lg = lg.next
            sr = sr.next

        return None
```

Comment: OP didn;t ask for code right now. Let him understand & try himself!

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you need to check the pointers, if there is same pointer in both linked lists then that is the point of intersection. These numbers just tell the value the nodes contain. Obviously, the intersection node will have same values, but same valued nodes may not be intersection points. Check the diagram on the example. Also note the input in your code is not just numerical lists, they are pointers. So work with pointers.

Comment: How do you generate such a linked list in code ?
I'm using STL i.e. std::forward_list<T> to represent a singly linkedlist.

I know it's possible to manually create each node and then do a list.insert_after()
so that we could later compare the addresses of the nodes.
But, is it possibly to generate the second list entirely/partly using some forward_list<> API to share the same node, while creating itself ?
For example : 
listTwo.insert_after(listTwo.begin(), std::next(listOne.begin(), 3), listOne.end());
creates new nodes, rather than sharing the existing nodes. Can we share nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

In that problem, we have to find that intersection point where the List has the same node(reference and value) not the only value.

**Example - 1:**

[image]

Here, the *Node with value **8** is the first one to have the same reference and value in both the Lists*. After that, all the nodes have the same value and references. While nodes with value 1 are the separate ones.

---

**Example - 2:**

[image]

Here the node with value **2** has the same reference and value in both the lists. After that, all the nodes have the same value and references.